# Nom pour qualifier celui qui dégage

Tags: substantivation

Dégager pris dans le sens I,B,4,C du trésor de la langue française TLFi: "Mettre en valeur une chose en la tirant d'un ensemble qui la valorisait mal". Exemple: Durkheim a dégagé la sociologie de l'ensemble sociologie-philosophie-psychologie. Qu'était Durkheim? Créateur c'est vrai mais ne rend pas raison de l'effet de séparation de l'un par rapport aux autres. Merci
Question reformulée car incorrectement posée comme "Nom pour l'action de dégager" Merci à Feelew pour l'avoir signalé.

Comment: Il aurait été préférable de modifier l'autre question plutôt qu'en poser une nouvelle. Du coup je me sens obligé de copier ma réponse.

Answer (score 1):

Je ne pense pas qu'il y ait un mot exact pour cela. Cependant, *"promoteur"* conviendrait assez puisque la sociologie a été promue par Durkheim au rang de science à part entière. Après, le souci avec *"promoteur"*, c'est que ce mot a aussi d'autres sens qui n'ont rien à voir (promoteur immobilier).

Dans tous les cas, et sans vraiment convoyer non plus le sens de *"séparation"* il y a quand même plus approprié que *"créateur"*. Outre *"promoteur"*, on utilisera *"pionnier"* ou *"fondateur"*.

Comment: Aussi: *initiateur*

Answer (score 0):

L'article de Wikipédia sur [Durkheim](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89mile_Durkheim) le qualifie de **fondateur** de la sociologie moderne.

À propos de [Lavoisier](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antoine_Lavoisier), l'encyclopédie le qualifie de **père** de la chimie moderne, qui se dégage des anciennes pratiques de l'alchimie et de la métallurgie.

Dans les deux cas, l'adjectif **moderne** évoque l'idée d'une création à partir d'éléments préexistants.